# Can submit event be cancelled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stop form from being submitted, and do something else instead (`window.location.href` redirect to pretty-printed URL). But I cannot even get the basic part of preventing form from submitting.

As far as I understand it something like this should work:

```
$(function($){
  $("#search_form").submit(function(e){
    console.log("cancelling submit");
    return false;
  });
});
```

I also tried `e.preventDefault()`, `e.stopPropagation()`, and various combinations of these. `"cancelling submit"` gets printed on Firebug console (so the event fires), but the form submits regardless, whatever I do.

jQuery documentation and logic imply that it should work, but it doesn't. Am I doing something wrong?

Hooking to click event might be easier but forms can be submitted in multiple ways - clicking buttons, pressing Enter, and probably something else I haven't thought about, so I'm trying to just take submit event.

I'm testing it all in Firefox.

EDIT: It turned out that `<button type='submit' onclick='this.form.submit()'>Search</button>` was causing this. It seems silly in retrospect. Thanks to everyone for help.

Comment: I think the whole point of the submit() method is that it happens ON submit. By definition, the form has already been submitted when that event fires and you try to return false.

Comment: Yeah, @kennis is right, i believe. Can you call the click event on the submit button instead?

Comment: If only there were a ohWaitNevermind() method.

Comment: The .submit() event is fired before the browser makes the http request, allowing you to run validation, process the form via ajax, etc then cancel the form submit request. The code provided works, there's something missing from this question that is causing the problem.

Comment: It'll probably help to post the code you have. There might be multiple `submit` events triggered.

Comment: @Ben Yup. Just tested. You're absolutely right. My bad.

Comment: TIP: fixing .submit() issues is tricky because the console doesn't keep state between pages. I would recommend using the error console (ctrl+shift+j) to diagnose any errors when dealing with .submit() problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just tested your code at: http://jsfiddle.net/UZwr5/

The code you've provided works in that demo. Most likely you have a error somewhere in your execution that prevents the `return false;` from running.

Answer (score 1):

try all of them together `return false` and `e.StopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()`

but more like this:

```
if(e.stopPropagation)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
}

if(e.preventDefault)
{
    e.preventDefault();
}

return false;
```

This keeps it much more cross browser compliant.